# consultation about ANN libraries

Tags: neural-network

Firstly, I am a beginner in artificial neural networks and I need a special library for training the artificial neural networks, but I very confused in the selection of the library, and since I didn't have the experience I wanted to consult you.
I have read about three libraries:
FANN, Flood, and Neuro Fusion libraries.

So, what are you think about the easiest and Least problems library for using it with VC++.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just started using FANN, and it seems to be very well documented, with great examples and fast.

It operates with floats/doubles/integers and implements the Cascade2 training method, which is really great if you are unsure about the architecture of your NN.

<del>It is not as rich as Encog (didn't use it), but</del> if FANN implements all the functionalities you need, I think you should go with it.

Edit: I just realized that [Encog](http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog) is only available for .NET C# (besides Java)